# How do you find the exact value of $\cos(\operatorname{arcsin}(\frac{-4}{5}))$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Step by step explanations would be helpful. It's my understanding that the above is equal to $\cos (\theta )$ but I don't know why. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Anon! $\color{blue}{\large{\text{Welcome to Math.SE!}}}$ Don't worry about it now but you might like to know that we use [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here (e.g. `$\theta$` for $\theta$) $\ddot\smile$

Comment: [Please read this too (just in case).](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/1804/80965)

Answer (score 5):

**Hint1**:

$\cos^{2}\alpha+\sin^{2}\alpha=1$. What does that produce for $\alpha=\arcsin\left(-\frac{4}{5}\right)$?

**Hint2**:

For any $x\in\left[-1,1\right]$ you have $\arcsin\left(x\right)\in\left[-\frac{1}{2}\pi,\frac{1}{2}\pi\right]$
and for $\alpha\in\left[-\frac{1}{2}\pi,\frac{1}{2}\pi\right]$ you
have $\cos\alpha\geq0$.

Comment: what about the  sign of $\cos\alpha?$

Comment: For any $x\in\left[-1,1\right]$ you have $\arcsin\left(x\right)\in\left[-\frac{1}{2}\pi,\frac{1}{2}\pi\right]$
and for $\alpha\in\left[-\frac{1}{2}\pi,\frac{1}{2}\pi\right]$ you
have $\cos\alpha\geq0$.

Comment: it should be contained in the answer

Comment: @labbhattacharjee The answer was originally meant to be a hint (incomplete). But I have given it an addendum at your request

Answer (score 2):

$\arcsin\left(-\frac{4}{5}\right)$ means the angle $\phi$ for which $\sin(\phi)=-\frac{4}{5}$, so $\cos(\arcsin(-\frac{4}{5}))=\cos(\phi)$

Comment: I know what it means but how do you find that angle

Answer (score 2):

Draw yourself a right triangle whose sine is $-\frac{4}{5}$ (which quadrant will it be in)? Then determine the third side of the triangle, and see what the cosine of that angle is.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\displaystyle\phi=\arcsin x$

$\displaystyle\implies(i)\sin\phi=x $

and $\displaystyle(ii) -\frac\pi2\le\phi\le\frac\pi2$ based on the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) of principal value of inverse sine

$\displaystyle\implies\cos\phi\ge0\implies \cos\phi=+\sqrt{1-\sin^2\phi}=+\sqrt{1-x^2} $

Put $\displaystyle x=-\frac45$

Comment: Downvoter , have you understood the method? If not, please pinpoint the confusion, else pinpoint the mistake

Answer (score 1):

Try considering something like this

[image: here is something to fill the space]

Comment: Or alternatively, to remove qualms about the negative sign, note that $\cos( \arcsin(-x))=\cos( -\arcsin(x))=\cos( \arcsin(x))$.

Comment: @Alyosha: My qualm is about the uniqueness of $\arcsin(x)$

Answer (score 1):

Consider any right angle triangle.  If we know two sides we can find the third, or in this case if we know the ratio of any two sides we can find the ratio for the third.

From Pythagoras we have

$$\text{hypotenuse}^2 = \text{opposite}^2 + \text{adjacent}^2$$

We want the angle with $\text{arcsin}\left( \frac{-4}{5} \right)$ and since $\sin ( \theta) = \frac{\text{opposite}}{hypotenuse}$ then ignoring signs for now we can find the length of the third side

$$
|\text{opposite}| = 4
$$

$$
|\text{hypotenuse}| = 5
$$

$$
|\text{adjacent}| = \sqrt{|\text{hypotenuse}|^2 - |\text{opposite}|^2} = \sqrt{5^2 - 4^2} = 3
$$

Now by convention since the the principle for arcsin gives angle $\theta$ where:
$- \frac{\pi}{2} \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ the cosine will be positive.

$$\cos(\theta) = \frac{\text{adjacent}}{hypotenuse} = \frac{3}{5} = 0.6$$